# How do I install Aeon on Ubuntu?

Tags: full-node, aeon, linux, ubuntu

I have a virtual machine with Ubuntu MATE installed. How do I install an Aeon node on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install the necessary prerequisites (on top of a default Ubuntu MATE image):

```
sudo apt-get install cmake g++ libboost-all-dev
```

Create a `git` directory:

```
mkdir git
cd git
```

Clone the GitHub repository:

```
git clone https://github.com/aeonix/aeon.git
cd aeon
```

Compile the sources:

```
make
```

After about 30 minutes, you'll end up with the following binaries in the `build/release/src` subdirectory:

```
-rwxrwxr-x 1 user user 3600096 Jan 26 14:44 aeond
-rwxrwxr-x 1 user user  829136 Jan 26 14:44 connectivity_tool
-rwxrwxr-x 1 user user  789768 Jan 26 14:46 simpleminer
-rwxrwxr-x 1 user user 2768864 Jan 26 14:47 simplewallet
```

When synching up the blockchain, if you have a nearby node available, use the `--add-priority-node` option to speed up the process, e.g.:

```
./aeond --add-priority-node <IP address>:11180
```