# Trouble compiling aeon node on ubuntu 16.10

Tags: aeon, linux, compile, ubuntu

I have a question, following the instructions on here:

[How do I install Aeon on Ubuntu?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/3477/how-do-i-install-aeon-on-ubuntu/3479#3479?newreg=2159b8204d4a4b5585ff673952ca548b)

I cannot get the node to compile on ubuntu 16.10. Here is what shows in the terminal:

make mkdir -p build/release cd build/release && cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ../.. -- Boost version: 1.61.0 -- Found the following Boost libraries: -- system -- filesystem -- thread -- date_time -- chrono -- regex -- serialization -- program_options -- atomic -- Found Git: /usr/bin/git -- Configuring done -- Generating done -- Build files have been written to: /home/bioniix/git/aeon/build/release cd build/release && make make[1]: Entering directory '/home/bioniix/git/aeon/build/release' make[2]: Entering directory '/home/bioniix/git/aeon/build/release' make[3]: Entering directory '/home/bioniix/git/aeon/build/release' make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/bioniix/git/aeon/build/release' make[3]: Entering directory '/home/bioniix/git/aeon/build/release' fatal: No names found, cannot describe anything. CMake Warning at src/version.cmake:3 (message): Cannot determine current revision. Make sure that you are building either from a Git working tree or from a source archive.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/bioniix/git/aeon/build/release' [ 0%] Built target version make[3]: Entering directory '/home/bioniix/git/aeon/build/release' make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/bioniix/git/aeon/build/release' make[3]: Entering directory '/home/bioniix/git/aeon/build/release' [ 1%] Building C object external/miniupnpc/CMakeFiles/upnpc-static.dir/igd_desc_parse.c.o In file included from /usr/include/stdio.h:27:0, from /home/bioniix/git/aeon/external/miniupnpc/igd_desc_parse.c:10: /usr/include/features.h:148:3: error: #warning "_BSD_SOURCE and _SVID_SOURCE are deprecated, use _DEFAULT_SOURCE" [-Werror=cpp] # warning "_BSD_SOURCE and _SVID_SOURCE are deprecated, use _DEFAULT_SOURCE" ~~~~~~ cc1: all warnings being treated as errors external/miniupnpc/CMakeFiles/upnpc-static.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'external/miniupnpc/CMakeFiles/upnpc-static.dir/igd_desc_parse.c.o' failed make[3]: *** [external/miniupnpc/CMakeFiles/upnpc-static.dir/igd_desc_parse.c.o] Error 1 make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/bioniix/git/aeon/build/release' CMakeFiles/Makefile2:140: recipe for target 'external/miniupnpc/CMakeFiles/upnpc-static.dir/all' failed make[2]:**  [external/miniupnpc/CMakeFiles/upnpc-static.dir/all] Error 2 make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/bioniix/git/aeon/build/release' Makefile:138: recipe for target 'all' failed make[1]:  **[all] Error 2 make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/bioniix/git/aeon/build/release' Makefile:20: recipe for target 'build-release' failed make: *** [build-release] Error 2

Answer (score 1):

Interesting. I added a single argument this time:

`git clone --single-branch https://github.com/aeonix/aeon.git`

By default this clones from the **master**, which I needed to do for macOS (to include some last-minute fixes), and I just reused the same syntax on Ubuntu MATE. Maybe regular Ubuntu behaves slightly differently. Please retest with that `--single-branch` flag. If it still fails, I suggest to ask on [Bitcointalk](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=641696.0), and relay your findings here.