# installing Aeon on Ubuntu

Tags: aeon, ubuntu, git

I'm trying to install Aeon on ubuntu following [this post](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/3477/how-do-i-install-aeon-on-ubuntu?newreg=4d6eadaa3c0f4a87b530fa88729980ea).

everything is fine until I try to use the "make" command. Then I keep getting an error for which I have no idea how to fix it:

```
mkdir -p build/release
cd build/release && cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ../..
-- Boost version: 1.54.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   system
--   filesystem
--   thread
--   date_time
--   chrono
--   regex
--   serialization
--   program_options
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:108 (message):
  Boost version 1.54 is unsupported, more details are available here
  http://goo.gl/RrCFmA


-- Found Git: /usr/bin/git
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Any clue?

Answer (score 2):

> Boost version 1.54 is unsupported, more details are available here
>   http://goo.gl/RrCFmA

What do you get when you run this: `sudo apt install libboost-all-dev`

Comment: Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree
    Reading state information... Done
    libboost-all-dev is already the newest version.
    0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.

Comment: Oh my Gaia, that link in the error message in from 2013. Have you checked "Compiling Aeon" section of the repo: https://github.com/aeonix/aeon

Comment: Actually, looking into whatever Aeon is, is this even Monero related? I see other Aeon questions on here, but I'm a little skeptical about that. I don't use Aeon. I probably can't help too much. Technically, I answered your question. The clue was in the text you pasted. Best of luck.

Comment: @Lorax Aeon started as a Monero fork and is considered on topic here: https://monero.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9/136

Comment: @seekadventure, great point. It's nonsensical to send the question to a forum that is even farther from the topic.